# C stdout printf

Tags: c, printf, stdout

I have a weird issue with printing data out. I use printf to print a char* string and then after that print another one. However part of the first string doesn't get printed and when I print the second string the missing part of the first one is prepended to that one. What is happening here?

I'm writting a simple libpcap implimentation. Here is a sample callback function that will produce the same results. I tried removing buffering and adding a putchar('\n') after printing but it didn't help.

```
void ParseData(u_char* useless, const struct pcap_pkthdr* pkthdr, const u_char* packet){
   int packetLen, i;
   packetLen = pkthdr->len;
   for (i = 0; i < packetLen; i++){
      putchar(packet[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show some code ? That might help.

Comment: Care to share example source code and output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stdio` buffers characters.  Unless you tell it otherwise, usually it will only actually issue a write when it sees a newline character.  If you want a different behavior, you can remedy it with some of these:

- After your first `printf`, call `fflush(stdout);` to flush the buffer.
- Alternatively, call `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` to disable buffering.  Do this before you do any `printf`s.
- Bypass `stdio` by coding to platform specific APIs like `write` (POSIX) or `WriteFile` (Windows).  Usually I would recommend against this, especially for something like `stdout`..

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility that your first printf is not having a '\n' at the end. In some cases the data might be buffered and printed together when a '\n' is encountered.

But, this is just a guess. Incase if you cannot post code, try the above.

Answer (score 1):

It's called file stream buffering.

You can disable it or change the size of the buffer using [setvbuf()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setvbuf). Or just [fflush()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fflush) after every print. However, the stream buffer is (normally) flushed when a line terminator (\n) is present.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar experience but this has more to do with double byte. I have 2 char* define back to back. I read some char into the first string. Turns out that is was double byte, so the remaining of the string spill over to the second string.